# Excel vacation days tracking

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a excel calendar that we use for vacation days.  Our leave year is April through the following March.  I would like to add a 13<sup>th</sup> sheet where in Column A would be an employee's name, Column B would be their starting leave balance.  Column C is where I would like to have a formula that would subtract 8 hours of leave from Column B and put that result in Column C whenever the employees name is added anywhere in the first 12 sheets.  Too make it a little more difficult, at times an employee would only take part of a day off.  It would be put on the calendar as "Johnson 2L" meaning that Johnson took 2 hours of late leave.  In that situation then Column C should only subtract 2 hours from Column B.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I am completely new to formulas.  I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What's the structure of your first 12 sheets?

Comment: The first 12 sheets are a single month of the current leave year.  It was an excel calendar I downloaded and altered slightly for our use.  For each day there is 4 to 6 "spots" to type in an employees name.  Is there some way to post the file here for viewing?

Comment: You can post a link to a screenshot on imageshack or something maybe.  But if not, you have days in column A and columns B-G are where their names might be typed?

Comment: Not exactly.  It is a calendar we print and post for employees to look at.  I scanned it and saved it as a jpg on imageschack.  I hand wrote the columns and rows for reference.  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/calendar0001.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

On Sheet13, paste each of these lines into C2 through O2, but make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then you can fill down with that formula.

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet1!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet1!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet1!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet1!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet2!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet2!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet2!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet2!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet3!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet3!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet3!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet3!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet4!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet4!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet4!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet4!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet5!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet5!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet5!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet5!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet6!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet6!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet6!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet6!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet7!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet7!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet7!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet7!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet8!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet8!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet8!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet8!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet9!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet9!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet9!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet9!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet10!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet10!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet10!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet10!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet11!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet11!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet11!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet11!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet12!B$4:O$33),0),IFERROR(1*MID(Sheet12!B$4:O$33,LEN(A2)+2,LEN(Sheet12!B$4:O$33)-LEN(a2)-2),IF(Sheet12!B$4:O$33=A2,8,0)),0))
=B2-SUM(C2:N2)
```

Some assumptions:

1. Sheet 13's row 1 is used for header names like name, starting, remaining.
2. Your first 12 sheets are called Sheet1 through Sheet12.
3. All the sheets look roughly like your scan, i.e., the area we want to search for names is B4:O33 on any given sheet.
4. There are no typos in people's names.

This will make a monthly total, and then a grand total in the O column.

Comment: I get an error saying formula contains more values, names, references than is allowed.  Could I email someone the file, might be easier than dealing with me, the formula newbie.

Comment: No worries, I think we can fix it here, just a sec

Comment: My sheets aren't named sheet1, sheet2, etc.  They are named Apr 2013, May 2013, Jun 2013, etc.  But I can always change the formula a little to correspond.  The range might be a little off on some as well but I can change that if needed.

Comment: Sure thing.  Don't forget to change all instances within the formula.  Also, since your sheet names have spaces in them, you'll need apostrophes surrounding the sheet names, like `'Apr 2013'!B$4:O$33`.

Comment: Will give it a shot tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.  WIll let you know if it worked

Comment: Getting values now, but they are off.  On sheet 13 "Johnson" is A2 and I put a starting balance of 200 in B2.  Johnson is on calendar 15 times, yet C2 is 192, D2 through N2 all say 200 and O2 says 2392.

Comment: Forgot to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Values for each sheet or month work, but not returning the correct number I'm looking for.  They are all subtracting individually from the starting balance and leaving a high number.  Should all be subtracting from starting balance leaving a much lower number based upon days off.

Comment: Oh, right, of course...sorry.  Fixing... (just removing the `B2-` from the beginning of each, then put it in the last one)

Comment: So did it work in the end?

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: No prob, glad to help.  Could you click the check mark to accept my answer?